# R pivot dataframe to reshape

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, data-wrangling

I have two data dataframes

```
Category = c("New", "Fixed" ,"Regular")
`Jan 2014` = c(-418518172, 24425087,0.3016606 )
`Feb 2014`=c(-168947846,17919651,-0.7212493)
`Mar 2014`=c(-168846,17544,-0.775493)
df1 <- data.frame(Category, `Jan 2014`, `Feb 2014`,`Mar 2014`, check.names = FALSE)
```

```
Category = c("New","Fixed" ,"Regular")
`Jan 2014` = c(-8172,-8524,0.5060900)
`Feb 2014`=c(-1686,19929,-0.85059894)
`Mar 2014`=c(-2424246,1232324,-0.7217593)
df2 <- data.frame(Category, `Jan 2014`, `Feb 2014`, `Mar 2014`,check.names = FALSE)
```

```
calculate_df <- cbind(df1,(df1[-1]/df2[-1])*100)
```

After doing some calculation i am trying to reshape it so that all the dates become`Date`column and then each type of `Category` `New` `Fixed` and `Regular` comes under separate column with their respective values.

```
reshape_df <- calculate_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !Category, 
    names_to = "Date", 
    values_to = "Values"
  )

calculate_df
```

**Current Output**

```
 Category Date       Values
   <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
 1 New      Jan 2014 -4.19e+8
 2 New      Feb 2014 -1.69e+8
 3 New      Mar 2014 -1.69e+5
 4 New      Jan 2014  5.12e+6
 5 New      Feb 2014  1.00e+7
 6 New      Mar 2014  6.96e+0
 7 Fixed    Jan 2014  2.44e+7
 8 Fixed    Feb 2014  1.79e+7
 9 Fixed    Mar 2014  1.75e+4
10 Fixed    Jan 2014 -2.87e+5
11 Fixed    Feb 2014  8.99e+4
12 Fixed    Mar 2014  1.42e+0
13 Regular  Jan 2014  3.02e-1
14 Regular  Feb 2014 -7.21e-1
15 Regular  Mar 2014 -7.75e-1
16 Regular  Jan 2014  5.96e+1
17 Regular  Feb 2014  8.48e+1
18 Regular  Mar 2014  1.07e+2
```

How can  i achieve the expected outcome?

**Expected Output**

```
 Date       Category    Values  Category  Values   Category  Values   

 1 Jan 2014    New      -4.19e+8 Fixed   2.44e+7   Regular   3.02e-1
 2 Feb 2014    New      -1.69e+8 Fixed   1.79e+7   Regular   -7.21e-1
 3 Mar 2014    New      -1.69e+5 Fixed   1.75e+4   Regular   -7.75e-1
 4 Jan 2014    New      5.12e+6  Fixed   -2.87e+5  Regular   5.96e+1
 5 Feb 2014    New      1.00e+7  Fixed   8.99e+4   Regular   8.48e+1
 6 Mar 2014    New      6.96e+0  Fixed   1.42e+0   Regular   1.07e+2
```

Comment: Your desired output has duplicate column names and therefore the data only makes sense printed in a particular order - I would discourage this.  Perhaps just columns `Date`, `New`, `Fixed, `Regular` would do the trick?

Comment: Keeping the long format appears to me to be good practice. Is it for publishing purposes?

Comment: @PGSA thanks that is a possibility but  `New Fixed Regular` are values inside `Category` Column how can transpose them to a Column ?

Comment: `pivot_wider()` is your friend there.  Off the op of my head, `pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = Values)

Comment: @PGSA thanks this gives me an error on Date `! Names must be unique. "Jan 2014" at locations 1 and 4. "Feb 2014" at locations 2 and 5 Mar 2014" at locations 3 and 6`

Comment: In your data set, what distinguishes the two `Jan 2014` entries?

Comment: @PGSA only the cateogty unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you may start from here (and, probably, you will find a less verbose solution soon).
Notice that, it appears unclear to me why wide is better than long. It is not good practice to have repeated column names. However, an exception might be publishing.

```
# to preserve the order of levels 
fb_split_df = \(x, f, ...) {
  f = factor(f, levels = unique(f))
  split(x, f, ...)
}
xyzzy = fb_split_df(reshape_df, reshape_df$Category) 
xyzzy[[1]] = xyzzy[[1]][c("Date", "Category", "Values")]
xyzzy[-1] = lapply(xyzzy[-1], \(x) transform(x, Date = NULL))
do.call(cbind, xyzzy) |> setNames(c("Date", rep(c("Category", "Values"), 3)))
```

gives

```
      Date Category        Values Category        Values Category      Values
1 Jan 2014      New -4.185182e+08    Fixed  2.442509e+07  Regular   0.3016606
2 Feb 2014      New -1.689478e+08    Fixed  1.791965e+07  Regular  -0.7212493
3 Mar 2014      New -1.688460e+05    Fixed  1.754400e+04  Regular  -0.7754930
4 Jan 2014      New  5.121368e+06    Fixed -2.865449e+05  Regular  59.6061175
5 Feb 2014      New  1.002063e+07    Fixed  8.991746e+04  Regular  84.7931106
6 Mar 2014      New  6.964887e+00    Fixed  1.423652e+00  Regular 107.4448227
```

Starting with `calculate_df`:

```
custom_reshape = \(df) {
  tdf = t(df) 
  cats = tdf[1, ]
  n = length(cats)
  tdf = tdf[-1, ]
  lapply(seq_len(ncol(tdf)), \(i) cbind(rep(cats[[i]], n), tdf[, i])) |> 
    do.call(cbind, args = _) |>
    data.frame(row.names(tdf), ... = _, row.names = NULL)
}
custom_reshape(calculate_df) |>
  setNames(c("Date", rep(c("Category", "Values"), 3)))
```